# Is it possible to create css animation without transitions?

Tags: css, animation

If I have the following:

```
@keyframes play {
    0%   {background:red;}
    25%  {background:green;}
    45%  {background:blue;}
    55%  {background:orange;}
    75%  {background:black;}
    100% {background:white;}
}
```

Is it possible to apply this animation to an element in a "discrete" way without transitioning between colors? For example, 25% of the way through the animation, I want the element to change suddenly from red to green. I tried using the steps(6) parameter with no luck.

If not, is there an alternative to do what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you set a key frame for 24% background:red and then 25% background:green ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NO TRICKS NEEDED**

The right way of doing this is through the [transition-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) property, that defines the effect between the steps of the animation.

One of the values is `step-end`, that skips the animation step to the end result, so:

```
-webkit-animation: play 5s step-end;
animation: play 5s step-end;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oe5nfy2L/1/

Comment: Perfect. This is just what I was looking for. The other suggested techniques will work as well (especially since they can be floating point percentages) but this is the right way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple trick.

```
@keyframes play {
    0%   {background:red;}
    24%  {background:red;}
    25%  {background:green;}
    44%  {background:green;}
    45%  {background:blue;}
    54%  {background:blue;}
    55%  {background:orange;}
    74%  {background:orange;}
    75%  {background:black;}
    99%  {background:black;}
    100% {background:white;}
}
```

Because I use chrome, I changed keyframes to webkit-keyframes.

http://jsfiddle.net/gfvyt9qc/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes play {
    0%   {background:red;}
    24%  {background:red;}
    25%  {background:green;}
    45%  {background:blue;}
    55%  {background:orange;}
    75%  {background:black;}
    100% {background:white;}
}
```

this could do the trick